# How can I use forwardRef() for circular dependency?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

How can I use forwardRef() for circular dependency? I did the same as the documentation but didn't work it gives me this error:
The module at index [1] of the GroupModule "imports" array is undefined.

Potential causes:

- A circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it. Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency
- The module at index [1] is of type "undefined". Check your import statements and the type of the module.

Scope [AppModule -> EntityModule -> BranchModule] +91ms

Comment: Did you resolve the problem? I have the same

Comment: sorry for the late response, you have to check all your services and model to see if there is a wrong import or injection that may need to be a circular dependency

Answer (score 2):

the circular dependency happened when two modules are calling each other, for example, if I have an animal module and a cats model calling each other:

in animal.module.ts:

```
import { forwardRef, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AnimalController } from './animal.controller';
import { AnimalService }    from './animal.service';
import { AnimalRepository } from './animal.repository';

@Module({
    imports: [
        forwardRef(() => CatModule),
        
    ],
    controllers: [AnimalController],
    providers  : [AnimalService, AnimalRepository],
    exports    : [AnimalService],
})
export class AnimalModule { }
```

in cat.module.ts:

```
import { forwardRef, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import {CatController } from './cat.controller';
import { CatService }    from './cat.service';
import { CatRepository } from './cat.repository';

@Module({
    imports: [
        forwardRef(() => AnimalModule),
        
    ],
    controllers: [CatController],
    providers  : [CatService, CatRepository],
    exports    : [CatService],
})
export class CatModule { }
```

in animal.service.ts:

```
export class AnimalService {

constructor(
   
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => CatService)) private readonly catService: CatService,
   

) {
   
}//rest of code here}
```

in cat.service.ts:

```
export class CatService {

constructor(

    @Inject(forwardRef(() => AnimalService)) private readonly animalService: AnimalService,


) {

}//rest of code here}
```